# Add PDF report button on TabPanel's header

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I want to add PDFreport button at the right of the header in TabPanel or may be on TabItem.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but i think you could try with [this method](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html#add%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

It allows you to put HTML code into the header of your TabPanel.
So you could insert your button as plain HTML into the header.

But it depends on what that button should do.

Comment: Unfourtinately, I'm using TabPanel from GXT, and they add method cannot take any widget, except of TabItem. But anyway thanks.